# Sum of column values in a file with field separator ',' in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

In unix I have a file like this:

```
43003.0000000,8191.1500000,10080.0500000
43003.0000000,8191.1500000,12096.4700000
43003.0000000,8191.1500000,727.8200000
```

I want sum column 3:

```
10080.0500000
12096.4700000
727.8200000
```

with this command:

```
awk '{a+=$2}END{printf "%012.2f\n",a}' file
```

But I have `00.00` because sum number between first '.' and first ','.

How to specify that field is until `','` ?

Thanks

Comment: You need the `-F` flag in awk. Which is documented in the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the delimiter:

```
awk -F, '{a+=$2}END{printf "%012.2f\n",a}' file
```

Without the delimiter the whole line is considered as `$1` by [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and there's no `$3` at all.